# Configuring second DC on Microsoft Azure

Tags: azure, active-directory

I try to configure a platform for our developers on Microsoft Azure.
I have to configure a new domain with a one way trust relationship with my main domain.
I created a Virtual Network with a VPN Tunnel, and successfully created my first DC and the new forest : rd.consoso.com (with my main domain beinf contoso.com)
When I try to add my second DC, I run into the famous DCPROMO Creating the NTDS Settings object error.
I tried the steps described here : https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2737935?wa=wsignin1.0 but couldn't solve the problem.
The local admin of the second DC is different from my Domain Admin.
I also tried to open the firewall as described here : https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh472161.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396#BKMK_KnownIssues
I tried to rename the second DC and change its IP

My VNet is configured with only the first DC as DNS server.
Both servers are WS2012R2 Datacenter

I can ping the servers from one another.

Any idea on this ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Ok someone gave me a solution on another forum :

1. Deactivate IPV6 from both machines on network connection
2. Deactivate 6to4 adapter if active :netsh interface 6to4 set state disabled

And that's it !